# How to check if a pair of values exist on a 2-dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2d array of that form:

```
int[][] moves ;
moves = new int[][]{{1, 2}, {1, -2}, {2, 1}, {2, -1}, {-1, 2},
            {-1, -2}, {-2, 1}, {-2, -1}};
```

and i want to check programmaticaly if a pair of values `{j,k}`
exist on my 2d array `moves`.

Comment: What do you mean by `{j,k}`? Do you mean similar values like `{j, j}`, or do you want to search for any pair of inputted values?

Comment: Any pair of integers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 

From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: I guess all of your answers are valid. Thanks and sorry for the inproper of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With java 8 you would write this one liner:

```
int[][] moves ;
moves = new int[][]{{1, 2}, {1, -2}, {2, 1}, {2, -1}, {-1, 2},
        {-1, -2}, {-2, 1}, {-2, -1}};

int [] t= {2,1};
boolean found = Arrays.stream(moves).anyMatch(m->Arrays.equals(m,t));
```

Comment: Surely this has the clearest intent and is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with an enhanced `for` loop:

```
boolean exists = false;
for (int[] move : moves) {
    if (move[0] == i && move[1] == j) {
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

At the end of the loop variable `exists` is set to `true` if a pair `{i, j}` exists in the `moves` array; otherwise, `exists` remains `false`.

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if(moves[i][0] == j && moves[i][1] == k)
        {
            //Executable code
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int x = 0; x < moves.length; ++x) {
    if (moves[x] != j) {
        continue;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < moves[x].length; ++y) {
        if (moves[x][y] == k) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

return false;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    int[][] moves;
    moves = new int[][] { { 1, 2 }, { 1, -2 }, { 2, 1 }, { 2, -1 }, { -1, 2 }, { -1, -2 }, { -2, 1 }, { -2, -1 } };
    int n = 1;
    int m = 2;
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < moves[0].length; j++) {
            if (moves[i][j] == n) {
                if (j < 1 && moves[i][j + 1] == m) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        System.out.println(String.format("[%d , %d] found", n, m));
    } else {
        System.out.println(String.format("[%d , %d] not found", n, m));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int[][] moves ;
moves = new int[][]{{1, 2}, {1, -2}, {2, 1}, {2, -1}, {-1, 2},
            {-1, -2}, {-2, 1}, {-2, -1}};

for(int j = 0; j < moves.length; j++){
    for(int k = 0; k < moves[j].length; k++){
        if(moves[j][k] != 0){
            System.out.println("Exist");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to check for specific index change `moves[j][k]` to your desired index. Or if you want to compare two values,

Change:

```
if(moves[j][k] != 0){
```

To:

```
if(moves[j] == 44 && moves[k] == 44){
```

If you want to return `true` or `false` rather than printing something you can use:

```
return true;
```

Or If you want to return values in specific index rather than printing something you can use:

```
return moves[j][k];
```